# Assign spotlight short cut to different keys

Tags: keyboard, spotlight

By default in Yosemite Spotlight shortcut is assigned to ⌘SPACE, but change language is also ⌘SPACE so for a multilingual person it turns out to be a tough choice which one to use. I am wondering if there is a way of assigning a different short cut as ⌥SPACE for a spotlight or the language switch?

I know I can disable language switch and only use 'next language' as ⌥⌘Space, but I am looking for an easy 2 keys solution

Comment: From `Preferences` -> `Spotlight` You can change Spotlight shortcut to any "Function" key (F1-F12).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just go to Preferences -> Keyboard. There you select the Shortcut tab and on the left Spotlight. Here you can enable/disable shortcuts and also customize them. Just click on the Shortcut on the right so it becomes selected and then press the new combination of keys you want to assign to it.

[image]

Hope that resolves your problem.

Best regards